# Progress Dialog in AsyncTask generating error on Activity Reference. Not an enclosing class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to send some data to web database using AsyncTask but it gives me error in this line in preExecute method when i try to initialize progress dialog.
dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.CustomAlertDialogStyle)

Error about MainActivity.this saying "mainactivity is not an enclosing class".

Here is my full code.

```
package com.cplusplusapp.rashidfaheem.hybridsoftwaresolutions.hbss.rashidfaheem.webservice;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner sp;
Button signup, login;
EditText edtname, edtemail, edtaddress, edtpassword, edtphone, edtcity;
String name,pass,add,catagory,phone,email,city;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] options = {"Student", "Teacher"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    edtname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtname);
    edtemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtemail);
    edtaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtaddress);
    edtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpassword);
    edtphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtphone);
    edtcity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtcity);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, options);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });

    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String permission="false";
            new adduser().execute(edtname.getText().toString(), edtemail.getText().toString(), edtpassword.getText().toString(),
                    edtcity.getText().toString(), edtphone.getText().toString(), edtaddress.getText().toString(), permission, sp.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
    });
}
}

class adduser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
Context mcontext;
ProgressDialog dialog;
HttpURLConnection conn;
URL url=null;


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.CustomAlertDialogStyle);
    dialog.setMessage("Registering User, Please Wait");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try{
        // Enter URL address where your php file resides
        url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1/rashid/signup.php");

    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Append parameters to URL
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.appendQueryParameter("customer_name", strings[0]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("customer_email", strings[1]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("customer_pass", strings[2]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("customer_city", strings[3]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("customer_contact", strings[4]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("customer_address", strings[5]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("permission", strings[6]);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("category", strings[7]);

        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        // Open connection for sending data
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        conn.connect();

    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        int code = conn.getResponseCode();

        // Check if successful connection made
        if (code== HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

            // Read data sent from server
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                result.append(line);
            }
            // Pass data to onPostExecute method
            return (result.toString());
        } else {
            return ("unsuccessfull");
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ("Exception");
    } finally {
        conn.disconnect();
    }


}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
        /* Here launching another activity when login successful. If you persist login state
            use sharedPreferences of Android. and logout button to clear sharedPreferences.
             */
        Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
        // If username and password does not match display a error message
        Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Register First", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Exception")|| result.equalsIgnoreCase("Unsuccessful")){
        Toast.makeText(mcontext, "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Initialise it in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Probably due to `adduser `is not  inner class of `MainActivity`

Comment: I have created this adduser class inside MainActivity class so why it isn't inner class?

Comment: There is not onCreate method in adduser class and after initializing it in MainActivity's onCreate method, it is not working in adduser class anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a class (MainActivity) that is inside it's own file from another class that is in its own file (adduser) . There is no way to do that - how is one class supposed to know about the other's instance magically? What you can do:

1. Move the AsyncTask so it is an inner class in MainActivity
2. Pass off your Activity to the AsyncTask (via its constructor) then acess using activityVariable.findViewById(); (I am using mActivity in the example below) Alternatively, your ApplicationContext (use proper naming convention, the A needs to be lowercase) is actually an instance of MainActivity you're good to go, so do ApplicationContext.findViewById();

Using the Constructor example:

```
public class adduser extends AsyncTask<Context, String, ArrayList<Card>>
{

Context ApplicationContext;
    Activity mActivity;

   public adduser (Activity activity)
   {
     super();
     mActivity = activity;
   }
```